# LDAP authentication in nestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, ldap, nestjs

I would like to get some help on how to do LDAP login & authentication in nestJS. I am searching for examples on the internet but never found it. Because I am new at javascript and also nestJS I can't understand node js so I can not make any progress. If there is an example you know, could you please, please share with me ?

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 4):

To do authentication using LDAP, you must have an LDAP admin user 'baseDN' details and password.
Refer below code with which you can connect to LDAP and authenticate the users.

```
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var cors = require('cors');

var passport = require('passport');

var ldapstrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

// connect to LDAP server

var OPTS = {

  server: {
    url: "LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389",     //LDAP URL 
    bindDN: "CN=adminAccount,DC=forumsys",      //Admin BaseDN details   
    bindCredentials: AdminCredentials,                  
    searchBase: "dc=forumsys",       //search base
    searchFilter: "(|(sAMAccountName={{username}})(employeeID={{username}}))",
    timeLimit: 3000,
  }
}

passport.use(new ldapstrategy(OPTS));

// instantiate the server
var app = express()

// parse the requested data automatically
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// allow cross-origin resource sharing
app.use(cors())

// inject LDAP connection to express server
app.use(passport.initialize())


// listen to port defined

const port = 8085            //process.env.PORT || 8085

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

  passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false},(err, user, info) => { 

    console.log(user)

    var error = err || info

    if (error){
        return res.send({
        status: 500,
        data: error
      })
    }       
    if (!user) {
        return res.send({
        status: 404,
        data: "User Not Found"
      })
    }
    else {
        return  res.send({
        status: 200,
        data: user
      })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})
```